# Python wrapper for pricing API

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a python wrapper for a pricing API. At the end of my code I make a method calls to the API endpoints. There are 4 different API endpoints. When I do a test run and hit the endpoints 3 out of the 4 endpoints return a JSON response except for the third one called "test3". Maybe its the way I formatted the URL response in my f-string? I have tried to format it differently but still keep getting this error.

Error here:
[image: image description goes here]

```
import http.client
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import json
import base64

 
def loadJson(response):
   body = response.read()
   if body == "" or body is None:
       print(("Empty response found with status " + str(response.status)))
       return {}
   else:
       return json.loads(body)
 
class data_pricing_client:
 
   def __init__(self, host, clientId, clientSecret):
       conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("sso.lukka.tech")
       path = "/oauth2/aus1imo2fqcx5Ik4Q0h8/v1/token"
       encodedData = base64.b64encode(bytes(f"{clientId}:{clientSecret}", "ISO-8859-1")).decode("ascii")
       authHeader = "Basic " + encodedData
       headers = {
           "Authorization": authHeader,
           "Accept": "application/json",
           "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
       }
       params = urllib.parse.urlencode({
           "grant_type": "client_credentials",
           "scope": "pricing"
       })
 
       conn.request("POST", path, params, headers)
       response = conn.getresponse()
 
       if response.status != 200:
           raise ApiErrorException(response.status, "Failed to get access token")
 
       self.host = host
       self.accessToken = loadJson(response)["access_token"]
 
   def default_headers(self):
       return {
           "Content-Type": "application/json",
           "Accept": "application/json",
           "Authorization": "Bearer " + self.accessToken
       }
  
   def send_message(self,path):
       conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(self.host)
       headers = self.default_headers()
       conn.request("GET", path, None, headers)
       response_json = loadJson(conn.getresponse())
       conn.close()
       return response_json
 
   def get_available_sources(self):
       path = "/v1/pricing/sources"
       return self.send_message(path)
 
   def get_source_details(self, sourceId):
       path = f"/v1/pricing/sources/{sourceId}/prices"
       return self.send_message(path)
 
   def get_latest_prices(self, sourceId, pairCodes=None, asOf=None, variances=False):
       query_params = {
           "pairCodes":pairCodes,
           "asOf":asOf
       }
       path = f"/v1/pricing/sources/{sourceId}/prices/{'/variances' if variances else ''}?{urllib.parse.urlencode({k: v for k, v in query_params.items() if v is not None})}"
       print(path)
       return self.send_message(path)
  
   def get_historical_prices(self, sourceId, pairCode, from_ts=None, to_ts=None, fill=None, limit=None, variances=False):
       query_params = {
           "from":from_ts,
           "to":to_ts,
           "fill": fill,
           "limit": limit
       }
       path = f"/v1/pricing/sources/{sourceId}/prices/pairs/{pairCode}{'/variances' if variances else ''}?{urllib.parse.urlencode({k: v for k, v in query_params.items() if v is not None})}"
       print(path)
       return self.send_message(path)
 
       
 
class ApiErrorException(Exception):
   def __init__(self, status, msg):
       self.msg = "Error " + str(status) + ": " + msg
   def __str__(self):
       return self.msg
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
   from pricing_api_creds import lukka_pricing
   c = data_pricing_client(**lukka_pricing)

   test1 = c.get_available_sources()
   test1 = c.send_message("/v1/pricing/sources")
   print(test1)

   test2 = c.get_source_details(3000)
   test2 = c.send_message("/v1/pricing/sources/")
   print(test2)

   test3 = c.get_latest_prices(3000)
   test3 = c.send_message("v1/pricing/sources/1000/prices")
   print(test3)
 
   test4 = c.get_historical_prices(1000, "XBT-USD",)
   test4=c.send_message("/v1/pricing/sources/1000/prices/pairs/XBT-USD")
   print(test4)
```

Comment: You get a response that is not json

Comment: Your code looks fine - it's the response from that specific API endpoint that is either not JSON, or malformed JSON. To be precise, looking at the exception indicates that the response is empty ("Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char: 0)"), so you're trying to parse JSON from an empty string.

Comment: That being said, your code is probably still the culprit, it's just impossible for us to tell what exactly is wrong without knowing what the API is. Confirm that the endpoint URL that you are constructing using an f-string is correct, and that your query-string parameters are correct.

Comment: For anyone who's curious, it looks like this is the [API endpoint](https://apidocs.lukka.tech/#01d325e1-cf9c-46b1-a6c7-dd62066e5eb7) in question.

Comment: Could it be that the request is invalid because the endpoint URL contains a trailing `?`, but no query-string parameters? Try removing the `?` when passing no query-string parameters, and see if you get a response...

Answer (score 0):

You can see that the error is thrown from the JSONDecoder. Possibilities are response is corrupted or the response is not a valid Json that can be mapped. Try logging the response to get an detail idea on it.